# Automapper.NET4.dll no longer included in build/bin - causing error in unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, umbraco

As this project is using Umbraco at its core, we are required to remain on a rather older version of the Automapper package in order to maintain support.

```
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Recently, we have seen bugs appear where before there were none in the DynamicMap function throwing the following:

```
Mapping types:
String -> Char
System.String -> System.Char
```

By manually copying the old Automapper.NET4.dll back into the application's BIN folder the issue is resolved.

Can anyone help me explain this?

Comment: Maybe some third party library included in your project is overwriting the dll with a newer version?

Comment: Hi, same as @Eyescream, you probably have a new package that is including a newer version of the AutoMapper DLL.
If this is the case, you can take a look at BindingRedirects, if you need to keep both versions of the DLL.
See the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Hope this helps.

Craig